# Why does Spring boot ignore spring.datasource.url in application.properties for my h2 database?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, h2

I have a Spring boot app that creates a h2 database and loads a bit of test data, which I then want to look at with the h2 console.

Here is my application.properties:

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:D:/ProgrammingStuff/wiktionaries/wiktdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

If I comment out the spring.datasource.url and Spring boot uses the default database path (jdbc:h2:mem:testdb), I can open the h2 console, connect to the db and look at the data. But If I specify the URL like above, the Spring boot console still displays the line `2023-12-29T10:23:56.665+01:00  INFO 9904 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration    : H2 console available at '/h2-console'. Database available at 'jdbc:h2:mem:testdb'`. And I can't connect to it using the given database URL, only the `jdbc:h2:mem:testdb` URL. Why would Spring boot ignore the JDBC URL I give?

The application.properties should also be in the right path: src/main/resources/application.properties
[image: application.properties]

Other maybe relevant files:

pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.pux12</groupId>
    <artifactId>dictionarycreator</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>dictionarycreator</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20231013</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jsonschema2pojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsonschema2pojo-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wiktionary</sourceDirectory>
                    <targetPackage>com.example.types</targetPackage>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

SpringJdbcConfig.java

```java
package com.pux12.dictionarycreator;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseType;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.pux12.dictionarycreator")
public class SpringJdbcConfig {
  @Bean
  public DataSource dataSource() {
    return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
        .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
        .addScript("classpath:jdbc/schema.sql")
        .addScript("classpath:jdbc/data.sql").build();
  }
}
```

Spring boot log:

```
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.2.1)

2023-12-29T10:49:54.327+01:00  INFO 14272 --- [  restartedMain] c.p.d.DictionarycreatorApplication       : Starting DictionarycreatorApplication using Java 21.0.1 with PID 14272 (C:\Users\hanne\Documents\Programme\dictionarycreator\target\classes started by hanne in C:\Users\hanne\Documents\Programme\dictionarycreator)
2023-12-29T10:49:54.332+01:00  INFO 14272 --- [  restartedMain] c.p.d.DictionarycreatorApplication       : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-12-29T10:49:54.418+01:00  INFO 14272 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2023-12-29T10:49:54.418+01:00  INFO 14272 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2023-12-29T10:49:56.425+01:00  INFO 14272 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with 
port 8080 (http)
2023-12-29T10:49:56.456+01:00  INFO 14272 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-12-29T10:49:56.458+01:00  INFO 14272 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.17]
2023-12-29T10:49:56.555+01:00  INFO 14272 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-12-29T10:49:56.558+01:00  INFO 14272 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2137 ms
2023-12-29T10:49:56.589+01:00  INFO 14272 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.d.e.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory        : Starting embedded database: url='jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=false', username='sa'
2023-12-29T10:49:56.860+01:00  INFO 14272 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration    : H2 console available at 
'/h2-console'. Database available at 'jdbc:h2:mem:testdb'
2023-12-29T10:49:57.775+01:00  INFO 14272 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2023-12-29T10:49:57.834+01:00  INFO 14272 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port 8080 (http) with context path ''
2023-12-29T10:49:57.853+01:00  INFO 14272 --- [  restartedMain] c.p.d.DictionarycreatorApplication       : Started DictionarycreatorApplication in 4.008 seconds (process running for 4.663)
```

Windows 10, Spring Boot 3.2.1, VS Code with Java extensions

Comment: When does Spring ignore your database URL? When starting the application or when running unit tests? In the latter case you have to add `@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = Replace.NONE)` to your test class.

Comment: @Karsten I run the application from the VS Code "Run" button of the SpringBootApplication, so the resulting console command seems to be ` c:; cd 'c:\Users\hanne\Documents\Programme\dictionarycreator'; & 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21\bin\java.exe' '@C:\Users\hanne\AppData\Local\Temp\cp_eo36bvpe1v1k5kd7hf80gd0m3.argfile' 'com.pux12.dictionarycreator.DictionarycreatorApplication' `

Comment: is `D:/ProgrammingStuff/wiktionaries` present? (it should (exist,) be empty or contain db files...if it contains `wiktdb*` files(!), then credentials should match..)

Comment: @xerx593 It exists as an empty folder.

Comment: @Pux, since you are creating the `DataSource` bean, it might not be taking into account the `spring.datasource` properties. Could you attempt changing the `DataSource` bean configuration by adding the name? For example, something like `.setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2).setName("file:D:/ProgrammingStuff/wiktionaries/wiktdb")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're manually creating the `Datasource` bean, it won't adhere to the configured `spring.datasource` settings. Specifically, when you use `.setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)`, it will generate the datasource with default configuration unless explicitly overridden during creation.

For additional details on `ConnectionProperties`, you can explore the default configurations utilized for H2 in `org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.H2EmbeddedDatabaseConfigurer`.

To update the database name in URL, you can modify the `Datasource` bean as follows:

```java
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
            .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
            .setName("custom_db")
            .addScripts("classpath:jdbc/schema.sql", "classpath:jdbc/data.sql")
            .build();
}
```

**EDIT**

When utilizing `EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder` with the `H2` type, it defaults to an in-memory database, and as of now, there isn't a straightforward way to customize this behavior. It might be worth considering reaching out to the development team to inquire about the possibility of adding this feature. As an alternative, if you prefer to use the file mode, you can achieve the same through configuration.

Here are some sample configurations:

```yaml
spring:
  h2:
    console:
      enabled: true
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:file:C:/data/sample    # Windows only
    username: sa
    password: sa
  sql:
    init:
      schema-locations: classpath:jdbc/schema.sql
      data-locations: classpath:jdbc/data.sql
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that really was the reason my application.properties were ignored. Unfortunately, setName seems to set the database path to memory. According to the Spring console, the resulting path from your code snippet is jdbc:h2:mem:file:D:/ProgrammingStuff/wiktionaries/wiktdb

Comment: @Pux In that scenario, why not exclusively utilize the `application.properties` file for initializing the datasource? This approach allows you to easily set the file path. If you also wish to incorporate scripts, you can achieve that through `spring.sql.init.schema-locations` and `spring.sql.init.data-locations`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, that really seems to work. (For some reason the database only seems to get filled when using an in-memory location though, so only for `jdbc:h2:mem:testdb`, but not for `jdbc:h2:file:D:/ProgrammingStuff/wiktionaries/wiktdb`.)